# Reduced Row Echelon Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Find all 4x2 matrices in rref form.

Attempt at solution.

A=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 
  \end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0  \\
    0 & 0  \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 
  \end{bmatrix}

Are there any more that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All matrices you showed are row equivalent (just interchange some rows). These are not row equivalent:
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},\, \begin{bmatrix} 1&k\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},\,\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix},\,\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Comment: You were still missing one. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg the zero one!

Comment: Easy to forget because no exercise ever asks to reduce the zero matrix. `:-)`

Comment: Very good answer. Thank you!